# T4 parameter directive using .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, t4, texttemplate

I have an issue in "CallContext.LogicalGetData" method using .net Core when i try to send parameter to runtime text template t4 (net core)

Below tt file :

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ parameter name="firstName" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="lastName" type="System.String" #>
```

and Cs call method :

```
            var pt1 = new ParamTemplate1();
            pt1.Session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            pt1.Session["firstName"] = "David";
            pt1.Session["lastName"] = "Giard";
            pt1.Initialize();
            var outputText1 = pt1.TransformText();
            Console.WriteLine(outputText1);
             Hello <#=firstName #> <#=lastName #>!
```

the problem is du to " System.Runtime.Remoting" library is not supported in .net core

Any ideas or workaround ??

Thanks.

Comment: Related (error at design-time, not runtime): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550265/t4-template-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4-2-0-0

Otherwise, lacking support for t4, you may want to consider Roslyn code gen instead (by hacking around with something like this): https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/02/create-a-class-with-net-core-and-roslyn/

Comment: @FrankAlvaro NET Core does not support .NET Remoting , this is the problem and i search for a workaround

Comment: Look at the Roslyn link in my previous comment. That *should* be compatible

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for the late reply, but if you still want to use the t4 templates, you can replace the parameters directives with properties at the end of the t4 document:

```
<#+
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
#>
```

And then call it:

```
var pt1 = new ParamTemplate1
{ 
    FirstName = "David",
    LastName = "Giard"
};
var outputText1 = pt1.TransformText();
Console.WriteLine(outputText1);
```