# T4 template System.Runtime issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-5, t4

I have a T4 template with simple code (ultimately I wanted to create template which creates SQL initial script with based on defined enums) :

```
    <# @ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)..\Core.Common\bin\Debug\net5.0\Common.dll" #> '
    <#
       var _type = typeof(Common.Consts.EnumDictionaries);
       var _const = Enum.GetNames(_type); #>
```

*EnumDictionaries* is a simple enum. 
When I'm trying to run it, it shows me following error:

> Running transformation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

I'm starting to dig deeper so enable fusion log and based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51550265/t4-template-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-version-4-2-0-0) I'm stuck on below error and have no idea how to fix it.

> Compiling transformation: The type 'Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

The error shows even I'm deleting the last of code.
I'm using VS 2019 and .NET 5.0

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: I am stick on this too. It seems that although it is perfectly fine to include and define even C# 9.0 code in the template file, you can't easily factor out utilities into "normal" assemblies and use them in templates via the "assembly" directive. My guess for now is that an assembly built for NET5 or 6 can't be loaded properly. Now trying to figure out if I can make it work with Netstandard 2.0 assemblies. Will report asap.